# importing files from other directories in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have the following directory structure.

```
A
 |---B
 |   |---C
 |   |---D
 |
 |
 |---E
 |   |---F
 |   |---G
```

I have A directory under which I have B and E. In B, I have C and D files and in E I have F and G files.

I am working on G file and I need to import D file. How do I do that ? If I directly write import "G.h" its throwing error as it will search in E folder. If I use import , its throwing error. Please let me know how to traverse directories in Xcode. I am using latest version of XCode (Xcode 4.6). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have added the files to the project correctly you should simply be able to write

```
#import "G.h"
```

as the physical location should not be an issue. Xcode should be keeping track of those.

Try removing and re-adding the files in question.

Answer (score 0):

You could add "B" to the "Header Search Paths" directly in the Project or Target Build Settings.

Add `"${SRCROOT}"` to `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` to include your source directory. In your Example it points to `A`. 
If you set it to `recursive` it will check all subfolders (including `B`).
With `"${SRCROOT}/B"` you would only include the header files in folder `B`.
The quotes are needed, if you have blank space in the path.

But you should not need to do that, if the desired file (G.h) is in you xcode-project.
Try re-adding the file as suggested by Mundi.

[Apple Developer Documentation: SRCROOT](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW38)

Comment: How do I add it to Header search paths ?

Comment: forgot to add @user1982519 in my comment - sorry