# Failing to link C code into Objective C: Undefined symbols for architecture arm64

Tags: c, objective-c, xcode, linker

I have some C code in my XCode project (using Objective C). I include the C file into a `MyHost.m` file like this:

```
#include <my_code.h>
```

And then call it like this:

```
my_function();
```

I've set up my project settings so that the **Header Search Paths** setting includes the directory containing my C code. However, when I build I get an error like this:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_my_function", referenced from:
      -[MyHost run] in MyHost.o
```

Why is the linker unable to link to the C code?

UPDATE: the reason I went down the path of using `#include <file.h>` instead of `#include "file.h"` is because the latter was failing to resolve the file. I found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014685/importing-files-from-other-directories-in-xcode) that suggests XCode should find my header file regardless of project structure. It isn't. Even after removing and re-adding the files it still doesn't resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

I had added the files as folders instead of groups. Groups are flattened by XCode and can therefore be included directly. Folders are not (but I still wasn't able to include by specifying a full path). Groups appear as yellow icons in the project view, whereas folders appear as blue.